# Google Calendar API. Adding an event to someone calendar throws error "Error 401: invalid_client" just when authenticating

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have a C# class library from which I am trying to add an event to someone calendar just by using his/her email address and password as credentials. So I debug it and once started a new page in the internet browser is open and below error is displayed:

[image]

Below the code:

```
// It crashes when calling GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "myGoogleAccount@gmail.com",
                    ClientSecret = "myGoogleAccountPasswordHere",
                },
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                System.Environment.UserName,
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

   // Create the service.
   var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
   });
```

Why this error is happening? ClientId is not the gmail account?
Also why a new page in internet browser is opened? I want to do authentication without opening a page in the internet browser because this class library is called from a windows service so I need authentication to be done in the background.

Comment: I suggest you read about [using OAuth 2 to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). You need a [GCP project](https://console.cloud.google.com/) with the Calendar API enabled to insert events to someone's Calendar. The Client ID is of your GCP project not the user you wish to create events for, and authentication can not be done in the background as each user needs to give your app authorisation to run on their behalf.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo thanks, ok,I understand. I have just created a Google Cloud Platform Project (GCP) and I have enabled the Calendar API by following this quick start: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet I have then obtained the client ID and secret and also I have dowload a json file with client configuration.Now I can insert events on the calendar. But just out of curiosity, Why Google forces you to create a GCP project in order to create events on someone calendar?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Also, Do I need to create a GCP project for each google account I want to create events for? Is there the possibility to create only one GCP project to manage all the accounts at once and create events for each of them through one GCP project?Regarding authorisation, is there any way to configure it in order to user always give this application his/her authorisation to run? so no need to do authorisation first time application tries to create an event on his/her calendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer:

*In order to insert methods into a user's Calendar, you need the user to give your application permission to make actions on their behalf. This is done using a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project, with OAuth2 Authentication.*

#### More Information:

Each application which runs and takes actions on behalf of a Google account user has to have the scope of its ability well defined so that it can't start doing things that a user hasn't given it permission to do.

**For example**: if you give an application permission to create Calendar events, you don't want it to be able to do other things such as read your emails or download the contents of your Drive.

In order to designate what your application has the power to do, it needs to be registered with Google. As you have already deduced in your question and comments, the Client ID and Client Secret required by an application connecting to a G Suite API isn't simply the username and password of a Google Account, but a designated ID-secret ID pair which is provided by Google to identify your application.

#### OAuth2:

OAuth2 is a specific authorisation framework. The framework is defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and sets out the process in which a user can authorise an application to access their account. The limit of the authorisation is defined by the scope of the application on authorisation, and can not be changed without explicit re-authorisation by the user.

Before continuing it's worth defining a few important terms here:

**User:**

> A user is the person; the individual that has an account and gives permission for an application to take actions on their behalf.

**Client or Application:**

> A Client or Application is a program which is designed to take actions over HTTP by connecting to a service's API. Applications can be mobile apps, web apps or desktop clients.

**Authorisation Server:**

> An Authorisation server is a server which is separate from the servers that store user resources. It verfies the user's identity and provides a grant which can be used to get an access token to a resource server.

**Resource Server:**

> This is the server where user data is stored. This could be anything from user information to files or emails.

The authorisation flow has already been well documented, but for the sake of this scenario we can abstract it down to the following steps:

- An Application wishes to take an action on a resource server on behalf of a user.
- The Application makes an authorisation request to the user. This is generally presented as a login page for the account for which the application is accessing.
- The user logs in to their account and is presented with an OAuth consent screen - this contains information such as the application's name, and the list of tasks that it is requesting authorisation for. These are often generic, and will say something like `See and download all your Google Drive files` or `View and edit events on all your calendars`. This allows the user to know *what* they are authorising before they confirm.
- An Authorisation Grant is given to the application.
- The Application provides the obtained authorisation grant along with its assigned client credentials to an authorisation server.
- On verifying that both the user's grant and the client's credentials are correct, the authorisation server returns an access token which can be used to access the requested and approved resources. *Note: This is normally all handled by your client library for whichever language you use*.
- The Application can now make a request to the resource server, providing the access token obtained from the authorisation flow. It is at this point that the permitted resources can be accessed.

#### Google Cloud Platform Projects:

A GCP project what Google sees as your application. The registration for your application is required to be able to obtain the client ID and client secret which your application will need in order to get an access token in the authorisation flow.
In the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) you can set up all the required services that your application needs. Each API you wish to use has to be enabled for your application, as [there are many Google services with APIs](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and they are disabled by default.

Once a GCP Project has been created, you can use the API Library (From the `≡ > APIs & Services > Library` menu item on the left) to find and enable the API. Note that for your use case you will want to enable the Google Calendar API and not the CalDAV API.

You will also need to set up a consent screen before obtaining credentials for your application. An OAuth consent screen is what your users will be presented with in the first step of the OAuth flow:

[image]

When setting up your OAuth consent screen, you will need to provide the following information:

- Application type (public or internal to your domain)
- Application name
- The scopes that your application needs (explained in the next section)

After the consent screen has been set up, you can download the client credentials for your application. With these, your application has permission to run as a client, but each user that has their resources accessed will still have to give their explicit permission to allow the application to do so.

#### Scopes:

Within a single API there can be many scopes of access - having read-only access to calendar events is vastly different to having complete read-write access to all calendars that a user owns. This is where scopes come into play.

A scope is defined as its namesake; that is to say, a scope defines the scope of access an application has to a service. Even though an entire API has been enabled for a project doesn't mean that you need to use all features of the API. For this reason, scopes need to be defined.

Scopes are defined in the application itself before making the initial request for the user grant. In C#, for example (taken from the [.NET Calendar API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet)):

```c#
// scopes are defined as an array of strings:
static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
...
UserCredential credential;
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

The access token that is stored is based on the scopes that were defined in the call. If a method is called which needs a different scope to those which the token grants access to, the call will fail with a `403: Unauthorized` error. The required scope will need to be added to the application, the old access token deleted and the user will need to grant permission for the new scopes.

#### Service Accounts:

As well as regular users, there is another special type of Google account called a Service Account. From the documentation:

> A service account is a special kind of account used by an application or a virtual machine (VM) instance, not a person. Applications use service accounts to make authorized API calls.

Normally, every user for whom you wish to perform tasks or access resources needs to give explicit permission for your application to do so. For G Suite domains, however, you can use a service account with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to complete tasks on behalf of users without the requirement.

Service accounts use a special kind of service-account credential which can be created in GCP and used in your application. Rather than making a `UserCredential` object, a `ServiceAccountCredential` is needed which [doesn't require involvment by an end user](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#serviceaccountcredential).

When running a service account on behalf of a user with domain-wide delegation, the name of the user needs to be specified in the delegated credentials so the application knows which user in the domain to run as. If a user is not provided, the service account will run the code as itself; which is useful in some cases but often times will not return an error and so it may not be clear for whom the operation was run.

**Note:** While Service Accounts can be created by anyone, domain-wide delegation of authority can only be accomplished for a G Suite domain, and not `@gmail.com` addresses. All Gmail account users ***must*** give explicit permission for an application to run on thier behalf as set out by the OAuth flow.

#### References:

- [Using OAuth2 to Access Google APIs | Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)
- [RFC 6749 - The OAuth2 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
- [OAuth - Wikipedia | #OAuth2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0)
- [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
- [Google APIs Explorer | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer)
- [.NET Quickstart | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet)
- [Service Accounts | Cloud IAM Documentation | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)
- [Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority | Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)
- [OAuth 2.0 | API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)

---

#### Related Questions:

- [Google API Service Account. Can only see service accounts drive even with Domain Wide Delegation Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892662/google-api-service-account-can-only-see-service-accounts-drive-even-with-domain/60927643)
- [Creating events using the Google Calendar API and Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473708)

Comment: Finally, I have created a service account, grant it a Project Role of Owner and enable domain wide delegation. Afterwards, I have created credentials for that service account so I can then get the client id and private key id (and also I can download a json file with the credentials) ...

Comment: ...Once I have done this, using client ID and private key id as client ID and Client secret respectively when authenticating in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync, I can access Google calendar and create events from my C# program without waiting the user to consent it through consent screen (consent screen does not appear anymore, no more consent screen opens in internet browser to ask for consent).