# What is the best way to allow a third party to access Alerts API data?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there a way to allow a third party to access Read-Only data from the Alerts API by giving them credentials? So far I've only read about allowing domain-wide delegation to allow an organization to query their own data using a service account. What if we'd like a third-party to read our alerts in order to analyze that data for us? Would that third party need to create an app in the marketplace for us to integrate with or is there a more direct way to give them programmatic access to our logs without having to export the logs out of the alerts dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You should develop the application yourself and use a service account with domain-wide delegation, authorising only the required scope for the third-party to use,* ***without*** *sharing your credentials.*

#### More Information:

Sharing credentials is considered bad practice and opens you and your company up to information leakage and data abuse - ***especially*** when used with the Admin API - these could then be taken and used inside another application to access other data if not properly restricted. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61778053/11551468) for information on where to set the service account's scopes.

The only scope available is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts` which is *not* a read-only scope. It limits the application's scope to only access Alerts data rather than the full Admin API, but it does also provide write access so these alerts will be able to be fully managed (`get`/`delete`/`undelete` etc).

#### References:

- [REST Resource: alerts | Alert Center API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/rest/v1beta1/alerts)

#### Related Reading:

- [Creating Google Calendar events with a GCP Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61778053/11551468)