# GMail create forwarding Address another domain-wide-delegation issue - PHP

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

I need my customers to forward me the emails received on their Gmail account from certain email addresses.

To avoid them to setup these rule manually,  I was wondering to use `Gmail APIs` to create a path where user just select the Gmail account and delegate us to setup the forwarding filter.

This works well, I can create/delete/list filters,
Problem arise when the forwarding email address is not already set, i.e. always:

To setup Forwarding address, `domain-wide-delegation` is required, and here starts my problems:

first of all is the meaning of `domain-wide-delegation` that makes me wonder:

domain would be gmail.com and clearly I'm not an admin of such domain

That means that what I'm trying to achieve it is not possible?

furthermore, I have another issue:

I created a `Service Account` and I have the
`Email`,
`Key ID`,
`Client ID`
`service_account.json` file with private key
and Domain Wide Delegation is set as `Enabled`

but I have not understood how to change the original routine in way of using Service Account instead of oAuth 2.0

I can imagine I have to change from using `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` to `service account`

Can someone explain how to use service account instead of oAuth?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915432/google-oauth-using-domain-wide-delegation-and-service-account/61932919#61932919 (you didn't specify language but here's how to do it with a JWT and node

Comment: Thanks Rafa.. I forgot to set PHP as language.
Will check JWT solution, but if you have some PHP suggestion, would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not super familiar with PHP, though have used it from time to time. Can take a look on Monday if you're still stuck from just the JWT solution, lmk :)

Comment: OK, I got Access_Token using JWT solution (but with empty subject!), but it is the whole procedure I have not understood:
I imagine I have to enter the gmail account in subject, but since I do not know such info I have to ask user to authenticate (and authorize) and then call again to get access_token
Furthermore to create a forward address it is stated that `Operations guarded by this scope are restricted to administrative use only. They are only available to Google Workspace customers using a service account with domain-wide delegation`
Therefore have to add also such option?
Thanks

Comment: I suggest to ask a new question for further clarification. Maybe there is some useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744176/creating-google-calendar-events-with-a-gcp-service-account/61778053#61778053)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I will try to make a new question, but from what I've understood I need a Google Workspace account and  all users has to be part of this workspace to be able to create the forward address via API. Furthermore, what is meant for "domain"?  is it real domain uri? i.e.: gmail.com because I have to generate forwarding address for gmail users.. therefore if domain is gmail.. I cannot be the manager..
Thanks