# Trying to log in with google with my app, but getting Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app with AWS cognito

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm working on an app that shows some specific analytics on my calendar, therefore I've implemented a Google Sign In in my app which also requests for calendar read-only permissions.

When I've tried to log in with my Google I got

> **Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app**

which totally makes sense, but I remember I had a few apps that used google sign in before it was verified (with calendar API also), but I got another screen that its risky, and the user could bypass it under his responsibility.

The app is currently in development status and I want to start working on it, but currently, I'm stuck due to this block by google.
Also, I got an email from google telling me to change this app type to internal but I want it to be external so other Gmail users could use it if they want to, I don't know where can I respond to this email.

Is there a way to start developing only with my user? 
How can I respond to the email from google? could not find anything on support, only billing

Comment: Set it to internal, you can change this setting later but it's unneeded during developement stages.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I want to try it on my email, and not some GSuite email. Also, before I'm buying a GSuite I want to test my solution on my account and make sure everything works correctly.

Comment: If you're using an @gmail.com account then yes you can only publish as external. [Due to the way OAuth works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61654179/11551468) you have to complete the consent screen process if you want to test your application with Google sign in, and there is no way around that.