# Google drive quickstart nodejs tutorial - how is quickstart the name of the application?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm following this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

In step 1, after pressing the button, I explicitly did not name my project as QuickStart when prompted.  Yet, when I run the app and I use the browser to authenticate, it asks about allowing QuickStart. I'm wondering where that information is stored.  I can't see it in the source code.  When I download the credential.json file, I don't see it there.  When I look on console.developers.com, I also don't see "QuickStart" there, but maybe I'm not sure where to look. Any idea where this is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This information is stored in the Google Cloud Platform console. You can change this by editing the OAuth consent screen of your project.*

#### More Information:

When you click the `Enable the Drive API` button on the Quickstart page, what is happening in the background is a GCP project is being created with the name `Quickstart`. This name is what is given to your project when registering it so that it can be set up for users to authorise. As it is a demo 'quickstart' project, this is the default name that it is given.

#### Changing the Project Name:

You can see all your GCP projects by visiting the [Google cloud platform console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Here, you can create, delete, and change the settings of projects that you have.

At the top of the page, on the blue header bar, there will be a dropdown menu next to the `Google Cloud Platform` title. Clicking this will open up a list of your GCP Projects - though if this is your first time using the APIs you will have only one, the one called `Quickstart`.

To change the name, you will need to open the hamburger menu on the top left and follow `≡ > APIs & Services > OAuth consent screen`. Here, you can click on `EDIT APP` next to the `Quickstart` title and change the application name to whatever you like.

There are other things on this page you can also edit, but if this is your first time using the G Suite APIs and/or the OAuth flow, I recommend reading up to get an overview of how the authentication process works and why this is important.

#### References:

- [Creating and managing projects | Resource Manager Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects)
- [Node.js Quickstart | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs)

#### Recommended Reading:

- [What is OAuth2 and how is it used with G Suite APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61654179/11551468)