# How do I use a Google Calendar scope?

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Currently, I am trying to use Google Calendar's API to create a program that allows me to add stuff to my calendar, the only problem is that I don't know how to add a scope to my program. Google tells me I have to use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" as a scope, how do I use this?

Comment: Have you imported the package?

Comment: I thought I imported my packages, I guess not. Just added them, Google's guide says I need to add a scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events. How would I add the scope?

Comment: That is a totally different question now. First you had compiler errors, now you have an API usage error. Please [edit] your question and remove the solved compiler errors. Make your example code a [mcve] and include the error in your question, not in a comment. Comments may or may not be displayed initially, and usually appear by number of votes, not chronologically.

Comment: Can you please post your auth code?

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how scopes works requires that you understand a bit about how Oauth2 works.

Oauth2 is a form of authentication where by an application requests permission to access some data from a user by displaying a consent form.   This consent form is populated by scopes which the application defines as the scope of access that it needs in order to run.

The Google authentication server supports a large number of scopes [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) they are split up by the API in which they are intended to access.

The Google Calendar API supports the follwing scopes. [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar)

[image]

Assume that you are using the [Google API Java client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client) library your code should already be controlling the scopes you are sending.  Look for the section that says `CalendarScopes`.

```
 GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.ALL)).setDataStoreFactory(
            dataStoreFactory).build();
```

Comment: More in-depth explanation of OAuth2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61654179/11551468).

Comment: Actually a more in-depth explanation of OAuth2 [here](https://oauth.net/2/)